# How do I retrieve photos from the cloud after I place them there?

Tags: photos

I recently uploaded photos from my iPad to iCloud.  Then deleted them from my iPad.  How do I retrieve selected ones and load them back onto my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Both iCloud Photo Library and iCloud Photo Stream are synchronisation services, and will do exactly that. Sync between devices.
Meaning that if you delete your photos from your iPad manually, they will also be deleted in the iCloud Photo Library unless you disabled this feature first.

Your best shot at retrieving your images is to check your "Recently deleted" folder on the iPad or after logging in to https://www.icloud.com under Photos.

Answer (score 0):

You can load them on your Mac (Photos app) / PC (iCloud for Windows) via iCloud Photo Library and then select the ones you want, copy to a folder and then upload them to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iCloud Photo Library to sync all your stuff across devices, once you delete your photo from your iPad, it will be deleted across all devices AFAIK.

Unless you mean something else by "upload" as in manually.